# SQL - Blank default namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have a relation which has an XML column storing data in the following structure

```
<Report id="b5d9b8da-7af4-4257-b825-b28af91dd833">
    <CreatedDate>04-12-2012</CreatedDate>
    <LastUpdated>04-12-2012</LastUpdated>
    <Reference>abc123</Reference>
</Report>
```

I'm writing a stored procedure to retrieve all reports and join them and wrap them in a root node called reports. I have the following so far;

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0')
        SELECT
    @Xml = 
    (

            SELECT
                (
                    SELECT xml.query('.')
                    FROM
                        [database].[Reports]
                    WHERE
                        ClientId = @clientId
                    FOR XML PATH(''),
                    TYPE
                )
            FOR XML PATH('Reports'),
            TYPE
        )
```

Whilst this returns all the reports in the right format, there exists a blank default namespace on the report element like the following;

```
<Reports xmlns="http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0">
<Report  xmlns="" id="b5d9b8da-7af4-4257-b825-b28af91dd833">
    <CreatedDate>04-12-2012</CreatedDate>
    <LastUpdated>04-12-2012</LastUpdated>
    <Reference>abc123</Reference>
</Report>
</Reports>
```

Could someone explain a suitable way of excluding the namespace on the report element?

Any help is greatly appreciated guys :)

Comment: Apologies, I am declaring a default namespace above the select with the following
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0')
If I didn't I wouldn't receive any results...

Comment: Has anyone came across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the column was not stored with a default namespace of "http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0".

So the logical name of your tag is NS = "", name =Report.

SQL Server is being absolutely correct.

What you would like to do is to say

> by the way, that XML data I stored, I want you to rewrite every tag from the "" namespace logically attached to every name, to a tag of the same relative name in the "http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0" namespace, and then make that the default namespace

AFAIK, You can't do that (but if you find a way let me know!). The closest you can get is cast it to `nvarchar(max)` with no namespace, then cast it back again with the desired namespace applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It makes perfect sense to me. I could write some code to clean up the blank namespaces but it seems more logical to just store them with the full namespaces. 

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little messy and probably not very efficient but you can redefine namespaces with an XQuery over your intermediate XML.

Instead of using SQL Server's `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` you declare the default namespace in XQuery, for example...

```sql
if object_id(N'Reports') is not null drop table [Reports];
go
create table [Reports] (
    [ClientId] int not null,
    [xml] [xml] not null
)
go
insert [Reports] ([ClientID], [xml])
    values (1, N'<Report id="b5d9b8da-7af4-4257-b825-b28af91dd833">
    <CreatedDate>04-12-2012</CreatedDate>
    <LastUpdated>04-12-2012</LastUpdated>
    <Reference>abc123</Reference>
</Report>');
go
declare @clientId int = 1
select  (
    select [xml].query('/*:Report')
    from [Reports]
    where ClientId = @clientId
    for xml path('Reports'), type
    ).query('declare default element namespace "http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0";
    for $x in /*:Reports return
        <Reports>
        {
            for $y in $x/*:Report return
            <Report>
                {attribute id {$y/@id}}
                {element CreatedDate {$y/*:CreatedDate/text()}}
                {element LastUpdated {$y/*:LastUpdated/text()}}
                {element Reference {$y/*:Reference/text()}}
            </Report>
        }
        </Reports>')
go
```

This will return the following block of XML:

```xml
<Reports xmlns="http://www.defaultnamespace.com/1.0">
  <Report id="b5d9b8da-7af4-4257-b825-b28af91dd833">
    <CreatedDate>04-12-2012</CreatedDate>
    <LastUpdated>04-12-2012</LastUpdated>
    <Reference>abc123</Reference>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```